# Using dask as for task scheduling to run machine learning models in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn, dask, dask-delayed

So basically what I want is to run ML Pipelines in parallel. 
I have been using scikit-learn, and I have decided to use `DaskGridSearchCV`.

I have is a list of `gridSearchCV = DaskGridSearchCV(pipeline, grid, scoring=evaluator)` objects, and I run each of them sequentially:

```
for gridSearchCV in list:
    gridSearchCV.fit(train_data, train_target)
    predicted = gridSearchCV.predict(test_data)
```

If I have N different `GridSearch` objects, I want to take advantage as much as possible of all the available resources. If there are resources to run 2, 3, 4, ... or N at the same time in parallel, I want to do so.

So I started trying a few things based on dask's documentation. First I tried `dask.threaded` and `dask.multiprocessing` but it ends up being slower and I keep getting:

`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py:540: UserWarning: Multiprocessing backed parallel loops cannot be nested below threads, setting n_jobs=1`

This is the code snippet:

```
def run_pipeline(self, gs, data):

    train_data, test_data, train_target, expected = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.25, random_state=33)

    model = gs.fit(train_data, train_target)
    predicted = gs.predict(test_data)


values = [delayed(run_pipeline)(gs, df) for gs in gs_list]
compute(*values, get=dask.threaded.get)
```

Maybe I am approaching this the wrong way, would you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: GridSearch is already parallelized: it tests across the grid in parallel.

Comment: @aryamccarthy thank you for your comment. Yes, but I have a list of GridSearch objects, for example one using DecisionTree and another with RandomForest. And I wanna run them in parallel as long as there are resources for it

Comment: There's no point though. It won't finish any faster.

Comment: If there are resources and they are completely independent, why not?

Comment: Because there's one resource that's not totally independent: your cores. You can only run one job per core at a time. Let's say you have n cores. Whether you have n separate gridsearches running one sim at a time or one gridsearch at a time running n sims, it's all the same in the end.

Comment: Is your question addressed? If not, what can be clarified?

Comment: And in a cluster environment, wouldn't this approach work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143687/discussion-between-larissa-leite-and-aryamccarthy).

Answer (score 3):

> Yes, but I have a list of GridSearch objects, for example one using DecisionTree and another with RandomForest. And I wanna run them in parallel as long as there are resources for it.

If this is your goal, I would merge them all into the same grid. Scikit-Learn Pipelines support grid-search across steps, which would allow you to do your search in only a single `GridSearchCV` object (for an example of this from the scikit-learn docs, see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_compare_reduction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-compare-reduction-py)). If you only have a single estimator (instead of a pipeline), you can use a `Pipeline` with a single step as a proxy. For example:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import dask_searchcv as dcv

pipeline = Pipeline([('est', DecisionTreeClassifier())])

grid = [
    {'est': [DecisionTreeClassifier()],
     'max_features': ['sqrt', 'log2'],
     # more parameters for DecisionTreeClassifier
    },
    {'est': [RandomForestClassifier()],
     'max_features': ['sqrt', 'log2'],
     # more parameters for RandomForesetClassifier
    },
    # more estimator/parameter subsets
]

gs = dcv.GridSearchCV(pipeline, grid)
gs.fit(train_data, train_target)
gs.predict(test_data)
```

Note that for this specific case (where all estimators share the same parameters, you can merge the grid:

```
grid = {'est': [DecisionTreeClassifier(), RandomForestClassifier()],
        'max_features': ['sqrt', 'log2'],
        # more parameters for all estimators}
```

---

As far as to why your delayed example didn't work - `dask.delayed` is for wrapping functions that *don't* call dask code. Since you're calling `fit` on a `dask_searchcv.GridSearchCV` object (which uses dask to compute) inside the delayed function (which also uses dask to compute), you're nesting calls to the dask scheduler, which can lead to poor performance at best, and weird bugs at worst.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! just one question before I try it out: in this line `pipeline = Pipeline([('est', DecisionTreeClassifier())])` is it correct to keep only the DecisionTree even though in the grid there can be N estimators?

Comment: In this case the `DecisionTreeClassifier` is just a placeholder - each parameter set in the grid includes a replacement for the `'est'` step, so it doesn't really matter what you put there. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, ok, I get it now! Thank you, I will give it a try and let you know how it goes

Comment: Is there a way to set different scoring metrics for the different estimators?

Comment: One way to do this would be to define your own scorer (signature `scorer(estimator, X, y)`, and use a different scorer inside that depending on the type of `estimator`. Then pass this to the `scoring` parameter of `GridSearchCV` (see docs http://dask-searchcv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#dask_searchcv.GridSearchCV),